# Yahoo Stock API Format

Tags: java, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am using yahoos stock api to pull information for my java application, I can pull high and low using

```
URL yahoofinance = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + 
        stocks[0] + "+" + stocks[1] + "&f=hg");
```

I figure that f=hg is for high and low of the stock but how could I pull P/E and other key metrics necessary for analytics?

Comment: Other thigs I am looking for is sector and average sector p/e and other things similar to that like 200 day moving average

Answer (score 0):

f=r will give you the P/E ratio and f=m4 will give you the 200 day moving average.

helpful reference: http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/